# UIScrollview in Uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController`. I am setting the delegate of the scrollview of the page like this:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
         UIScrollView *pageScrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
        [pageScrollView setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Now when i set the content offset:

```
[pageScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(125, 0)];
```

How do i explicitly call the

```
- (nullable UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and

```
- (nullable UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

in order to load the next view controller ? 
FYI: The contentoffset is being set in an add observer method.

Comment: I don't understand the goal. Normally, you would set the delegate of `UIPageViewController` and implement those delegate methods accordingly (rather than explicitly call them).

Comment: @BenJammin i have a separate scrollview ...when i scroll this scrollview the page should scroll along with this scrollview.